# probability with cards blue red green

Tags: probability

So I have a really problem with probability so sorry for this question really easy but I don't understand how to solve this problem ...

So there is the problem :

We are playing with a card game with 42 cards there is 14 differents value and 3 color (blue/red/green) . We pick 5cards randomly . What is the probability to have different value on all cards pick?

Comment: Hint: How many choices do you have for the first card? How many then for the second. Then the third.

Comment: 42 for the first , 41 the second , 40 the third, 39 for the fourth and 38 for the fifth ?

Comment: I have made this : 

1+ 39/41 + 36/40 + 33/39 + 30/38 ...

But this is not good I think

Comment: The second card must have a different value - are there 41 of those?

Comment: there is 39 value of those ?

Comment: 38 - 4 cards with the same value from 42. So now 8 cards cannot be chosen. Carry on for cards 3, 4, 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a card. Then again pick a card. What is the probability that its value differs from the value of the first card? There are $41$ in total (one of them is allready picked out). How many of these cards have a value that differs from the value of the first card? Then go on by picking a third card and ask the question: if the first and the second have indeed different values, then what is the probability that the third card has a value that differs from the values of the cards allready drawn? I hope this put you on the right track.

---

$\frac{42}{42}\times\frac{39}{41}\times\cdots$

Comment: yes but when I have all the probability what I have to do with ? adding them together ? or multiply them ? and how I can know if I have to multiply or add ?

Comment: If you have 3 cards with different values and you want to pick 2 you can do it in 3 times 2 = 6 ways (3 choices for the first, 2 for the second).

Comment: I have do this : 1*(39/41)*(36/40)*(33/39)*(30/38) = 0.5718

This is the good answer . But I still don't know if I have to add or multiply when I have probability . :/

Comment: $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ if the events are disjoint (addition). $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ if the events are independent (multiplication). If the events are not independent then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B\mid A)$. This is the case you are dealing with here.

Comment: why 38/41? this is 39/41 no?

Comment: You are right. One card has been picked. Among the $41$ left there are $2$ that have the same value as the first card, so $41-2=39$ have a different value. I was (wrongly) thinking in $4$ colours (I got to much used to that number of colors)